# How do I update a setting in an Azure Role via the powershell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to update one Role Setting (the ones in the *.cscfg file) via the [Azure powershell cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn495240.aspx).
I know this is possible via the Azure Portal but I have not found any such command in the cmdlets.

Does anyone know how to change a *.cscfg Setting from a running Azure Role using the powershell cmdlets? (and without having to upload a new *.cspkg file)

Thanks,
rui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmdlet you would want to use is [`Set-AzureDeployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn495140.aspx) with `-Config` parameter set. You would need to provide the entire configuration file. Essentially you would need to make changes in the config file and then call this cmdlet and provide the new config file. You don't need to upload new package file for changing configuration settings.